# Avoide duplicate id in the response

Tags: mysql

I am trying to accomplish the following sql statement but I am getting one duplicate id in my response.

```
SELECT ci.customer_id,
       ci.first_name,
       ci.user_gender,
       ci.customer_status,
       fr.relation
FROM   customerinfo ci
       INNER JOIN familyrelation fr
               ON ( fr.personid_two = ci.customer_id )
WHERE  ci.customer_id IN (SELECT personid_two
                          FROM   familyrelation
                          WHERE  personid_one = 17)
       AND ci.csp_user_id = 5;
```

When i run this query, I am fetching the proper result, but one **customer_id** is getting repeated. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Because you join. So what data do you want if you have 2 records in the joined table? You need to be way more specific than this! Add example data and expected output

Comment: there is no problem in fetching the records. But same customer_id is getting duplicated once-again. @juergend

Comment: You don't get why you get duplicates. It is because there are sometimes 2 records in the joined table for the same record in custimerinfo. And now think about which one of those 2 you want and why.

Answer (score 0):

If your data looks like this

```
drop table if exists ci,fr;
create table ci(customer_id int, name varchar(3),csp_user_id int);
create table fr(personid_one int,personid_two int,relation varchar(10));

insert into ci values (1,'aaa',5),(2,'bbb',5);
insert into fr values (17,1,'mother'),(17,1,'father'),(17,2,'niece');
```

Then your query selects the rows I would expect

```
SELECT ci.customer_id,
       ci.name,
       fr.relation
FROM   ci
       INNER JOIN  fr
               ON ( fr.personid_two = ci.customer_id )
WHERE  ci.customer_id IN (SELECT personid_two
                          FROM   fr
                          WHERE  personid_one = 17)
AND ci.csp_user_id = 5;  

 +-------------+------+----------+
| customer_id | name | relation |
+-------------+------+----------+
|           1 | aaa  | mother   |
|           1 | aaa  | father   |
|           2 | bbb  | niece    |
+-------------+------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```